# Finding Integrals of Piecewise Functions

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)$ be a piecewise function as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}3&x<0\\x&0<x<1\\3&x>1\end{cases}$$

(So $f$ is undefined at $0$ and $1$.) What would be an anti-derivative of f?

Here's what I've done so far: I know the anti-derivative will also be piecewise. I think I should find the anti-derivative of $3$ and the anti-derivative of $x$ which would be $3x+c$ and $\frac{x^2}2+c$ respectively? Is it that easy or am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: I've reformatted, let me know if this is not what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

There is no anti-derivative for $f$ on $\mathbb R$. This is because the derivative of any function has IVP and your function $f$ does not have IVP. It attains the values $\frac  1 2$ and $3$ but never attains the value $2$. [IVP is Interemediate Value Property. IVP of derivatives is called Darboux Theorem].

Of course, $f$ has anti-derivatines in each of the intervals $(-\infty, 0), (0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ and you already know what thwse are.

Comment: What does IVP stand for?

Comment: @quaziquincy I have edited my answer.

Comment: Even if there is no anti-derivative on ℝ, could there still be an anti-derivative at x <0 or x > 1?

Comment: @quaziquincy I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! So there is a piecewise anti derivative and it would be 3x+c, (x^2/2), and 3x+c, respectively? Or does the second one not exist because it violates IVP?

Comment: The second one also exists. You forgot the constant there.